# Python 3 BS4 - Return First <td> in Specified <tr>

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

Looking to get the first value in an HTML table row. The HTML table row simply looks like:

```
Buy       Sell       Sell
```

...and my code looks like:

```
page = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')
table = soup.findAll('tr', {'class' :'last'})
for r in range(len(table)):
    print(table[r].text)
```

...which currently returns:

```
Buy
Sell
Sell
```

...as it should, however I want to only retrieve the "Buy" value. If it helps, the HTML locator for that value is

```
td class = "current" .... </td
```

I've tried playing with the slice feature [1], [-1], [1:1], etc. all over my code, but can't seem to figure it out. Can someone assist? Thanks a million.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use `.find()` instead of `.findAll()` to get the first match:

```
soup.find('tr', {'class': 'last'}).get_text()
```

Or, if you need to get to the first inner `td` element of the first `tr`:

```
soup.find('tr', {'class': 'last'}).td.get_text()
```

where `.td` is a shorthand for `.find("td")`.

---

Or, you can enforce the `current` class check (assuming you are going after the contents of the inner `td` element):

```
soup.select_one("tr.last td.current").get_text()
```

where `tr.last td.current` is a [CSS selector](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors) that would match a `td` element having `current` class inside the `tr` element having `last` class.

Comment: The Current option worked like a charm. I forgot to mention that actually the first td was a different value, but the value I wanted was the one with the class="Current" anyway, so that solution worked great. Thanks so much!